# Is there a way to remove a string from a line of a csv using sed in bash scripts?

Tags: csv, sed

I have a scv file that is currently formatted like this:

```
INSERT INTO `kindle_reviews` VALUES (stuff I want); INSERT INTO `kindle_reviews` VALUES (stuff I want);
```

I would like to obtain the (stuff I want) and remove the 'INSERT INTO `kindle_reviews` VALUES ' part of every line.

Some command I tried on terminal:

```
sed -i -e 's/INSERT INTO 'kindle_reviews' VALUES //g' Untitled.csv
```

This did not work due to this error:

```
sed: 1: "s|</td><td><INSERT INTO ...": unterminated substitute pattern
```

Is it possible to remove a substring on every line of the csv file? Thank you very much

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts, please do add samples of input and expected output too in your question and let us know then.

Comment: What is the exact output you expect here?

Comment: The output I would like to get are the values that are inside the brackets. The data inside the brackets are in the form of a csv. This csv is what I would like to extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't have apostrophes (`'`) inside a string that is itself delimited by apostrophes. Use something like this:

```
sed -i -e 's/INSERT INTO '\''kindle_reviews'\'' VALUES //g' Untitled.csv
```

But are you sure those are apostrophes? Your sample line has backquotes (`) instead:

```
sed -i -e 's/INSERT INTO `kindle_reviews` VALUES //g' Untitled.csv
```

And the backquotes make it valid MySQL; the version with apostrophes is not. (You could also find double-quotes, e.g. `INSERT INTO "kindle_reviews"`.)

If you want just the part between the parentheses (brackets), that'd be more like this:

```
sed -i -e \
  's/INSERT INTO `kindle_reviews` VALUES (\(.*\)).*$/\1/'
```

But only if everything between the parentheses is on a single line.

However, if want to get data out of a MySQL table into a CSV file, I don't know why you'd be dumping it as SQL INSERT commands in the first place. If you have access to the original database, you can export it directly as a CSV with something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `kindle_reviews` 
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/kindle_reviews.csv' 
  FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
  TERMINATED BY ';' 
  ESCAPED BY '"' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Comment: Yup, the csv we got from our mysql gives us the msql commands. I am trying to remove these commands such that we have a 'clean' csv file without the commands. I have tried the above commands, but the file remains unaltered. The command runs without any error though.

Comment: See edit. The actual MySQL, like your first line, probably has backquotes (\`), not apostrophes (').

Comment: You are right! I did what you said and got the output that I wanted. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Also, with regards to your sql commands, the problem we faced were permission issues. There was no way to run the sql commands on terminal because we did not have the proper permissions. That is why we resorted to csv dumping.